# I have a code which is sending emails from salesforce

Tags: apex

> the governor limits are being hit need to use an external client to avoid this. can any one suggest an alternative

**Visual Force Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="selection1" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      font: normal 14px Verdana, Calibri;
    }
  </style>
  <apex:outputPanel id="jsFunctions">
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      console.log('{!selectedTmplID}');
      function mailto1() {
        console.log('{!selectedContacts}');
      }
    </script>
  </apex:outputPanel>
</head>
<body>
  <apex:form id="fm">

    <div align="left" draggable="false" >
      <apex:commandButton value="Send" action="{!sendMails}" rerender="jsFunctions" />
    </div>


    <!-- apex:repeat var="ebj" value="{!refs}">
      <b>{!ebj.name}</b>:<p>{!ebj.email}</p><br/>
    </apex:repeat> -->

    <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
      <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs" >
        <apex:selectcheckboxes layout="pageDirection" id="checkbx" value="{!selectedContacts}">
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}" />
          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="jsFunctions" />
        </apex:selectcheckboxes>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock id="emailTemplateBlock">
      Select A Template:<br/>
      <apex:selectList value="{!selectedTmplID}" multiselect="false" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!emailTemplateOpts}" />
      </apex:selectList>
    </apex:pageBlock>  
  </apex:form>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

**APEX CLASS**

```
public class selection1 {
  public String selectedEmail1{get;set;}
  public String selectedTmpl{get;set;}
  public String[] selectedEmails{get;set;}
  public ID[] selectedContacts{get;set;}
  public ID selectedTmplID{get;set;}
  public String emailid{get;set;}
  public List<MailRef> refs{get;set;}
  private List<EmailTemplate> ABMMEmailTemplates;
  private List<Folder> allEmailTemplateFolders;
  //private List<Folder> allEmailTemplateFolders;
  //public String selectedEmailTemplateFolder {public get; public set;}
  public String selectedEmailTemplate {public get; public set;}
  public EmailTemplate chosenEmailTemplate {public get; private set;}

  public String Rcdids;
  public list<wrapper> listWrap{get;set;}

  public selection1() {
    listWrap =new list<Wrapper>();
        //ABMMEmailTemplates = [select Id, Name, Subject, Body, FolderId from EmailTemplate where order by Name asc];
    ABMMEmailTemplates = [select Id, Name, Subject, Body, FolderId from EmailTemplate where NOT Name Like '%Sup%'];    
    emailid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('name');
    Rcdids = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Rcdid');
    if(Rcdids !=null && Rcdids !='')
      Rcdids =Rcdids.substring(0, Rcdids.length() - 1);
    system.debug('Rcdids &&'+Rcdids);
    String JSONContent = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('mails');
    selectedTmpl = 'Blank Email';
    selectedEmails = new String[]{};
    selectedContacts = new Id[]{};
    selectedTmplID = null;
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(JSONContent);
    Integer i = 0;
    String key;
    String val;
    refs = new List<MailRef>();
    MailRef obj = new MailRef();
    refs.add(obj);
    while(parser.nextToken() != null) {
      key = parser.getCurrentName();
      if (key == null) continue;
      // First key should be name
      if (key == 'name') {
        parser.nextToken();
        val = parser.getText();
          if (obj.name != null) { // meaning obj already has name.
            obj = new MailRef();
            refs.add(obj);
          }
        obj.name = val;
      }
      // Second key should be email.
      if (key == 'email') {
        parser.nextToken();
        val = parser.getText();
        if (obj.email != null) { // meaning obj already has email.
          obj = new MailRef();
          refs.add(obj);
        }
        obj.email = val;
      }
    }
  }

  public List<SelectOption> getEmailTemplateFolderOpts() {
    List<SelectOption> opts = new List<SelectOption>();
    opts.add(new SelectOption('null', ' - Select - '));

    for ( Folder f : allEmailTemplateFolders )
      opts.add(new SelectOption(f.Id, f.Name));

    // add an option for templates in the Unfiled Public folder
    opts.add(new SelectOption(UserInfo.getOrganizationId(), 'ABMMTemplates'));
    return opts;
  }

  public List<SelectOption> getEmailTemplateOpts() {
    List<SelectOption> opts = new List<SelectOption>();
    opts.add(new SelectOption('null', ' - Select - '));

    for (EmailTemplate et: ABMMEmailTemplates) {
      opts.add(new SelectOption(et.Id, et.Name));
    }
    return opts;
  }


  public List<SelectOption> getOptions() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    set<id> setids = new set<id>();
    list<String> listStr= Rcdids.split(',');
    map<Integer,String> mapInter = new map<integer,String>();
    for(integer i=0; i<listStr.size(); i++){
      mapInter.put(i,listStr[i]);
    }
    list<contact> listcon =[select id,name,Email from contact where id in:mapInter.Values()];
    map<id,Contact> mapcon = new map<id,Contact>();
    for(Contact objCon:listcon){

      mapcon.put(objCon.id,objCon);
    }
    for (Integer i = 0; i < listcon.size(); i++) {
      String strcon = mapInter.get(i);
      SelectOption option = new SelectOption(mapcon.get(strcon).id, mapcon.get(strcon).Name);
      options.add(option);
   }
   return options;
  }

  public static void sendEmail(ID recipient, ID candidate, ID template, Blob doc) {
    //New instance of a single email message
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    // Who you are sending the email to
    mail.setTargetObjectId(recipient);
    mail.setCcAddresses(new String[] {'satyasrinivas@neosofttech.com'});

    // The email template ID used for the email
    mail.setTemplateID(template);

    // What information are you sending?
    // mail.setWhatId(candidate);

    mail.setBccSender(false);
    mail.setUseSignature(false);

    // mail.setReplyTo('');
    // mail.setSenderDisplayName('');

    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
  }

  public static void sendEmail(ID recipient, ID candidate, ID template) {
    sendEmail(recipient, candidate, template, null);
  }

  public void sendMails() {
    if (selectedContacts == null || selectedContacts.size() == 0 || selectedTmplID == null) {
      return;
    }
    for (ID i: selectedContacts) {
      sendEmail(i, i, selectedTmplID);
    }    
  }

  public PageReference save() {
    return null;
  }

  public class RefWrapper {
    public List<MailRef> refers{get;set;}
  }

  public class MailRef {
    public String name{get;set;}
    public String email{get;set;}
  }

  public class wrapper{
    public boolean isselected {get;set;}
    public contact con{get;set;}
  }
}
```

Comment: public void sendMails() {  if (selectedContacts == null || selectedContacts.size() == 0 || selectedTmplID == null) {
 return; }  List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail;
 for (ID i: selectedContacts) {  mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); mail.setTargetObjectId(recipient);
 mail.setCcAddresses(new String[];  mail.setBccSender(false); mail.setUseSignature(false);  mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);  // sendEmail(i, i, selectedTmplID);  emails.add( mail); }     Messaging.sendEmails(emails); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an external client. You just need to follow a very common pattern, namely:

- instantiate a collection outside (before) your loop
- add elements within the loop
- call your method which consumes governors outside the loop

  - this way you just take one governor hit on the entire collection.

**Not Bulkified**

```
for (...)
{
    Messaging.sendEmail(...)
}
```

**Bulkified**

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for (...)
{
    emails.add(...)
}
Messaging.sendEmails(emails)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I am trying to open Outlook before sending the email to make small changes to the saved template, this is the reason for trying to get this sorted out as the email is sent out without any visibilty and I am unable to make changes in the content.

Comment: There are many options with the currently available apps, however I am using a few customization of my own.

Comment: In the above code can we manage to save the output as a word document in place of sending an email

Comment: @nallanichakravartula That is a completely different question, and should be asked as a separate post. Please avoid asking complex follow up questions in the comments.